# How to set cursor position on the first line at Telerik’s RadEditor programmatically?

Tags: jquery, telerik, radeditor

I am using Telerik's Radeditor and when the editor loads,I want to set the cursor position on the first line at position 1.
The radeditor's [Api doc](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-setfocus.html) says that the following command does the job:

```
docEditor.setFocus();
```

and i also found this method:

```
getRange();
```

[getRange](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getrange.html) ,not working either!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
At your Radeditor's `OnClientLoad` method put inside the following commands (tleditor represents the radeditor's object):

```
var range = tleditor.getSelection().getRange(true); //returns an object that represents a restore point.
    tleditor.getSelection().selectRange(range);

    setTimeout(function () {
        tleditor.setFocus();
    }, 0);
```

and this will exactly focus at the first position and if there is content inside.

I hope this helps you either!